# Angular service/factory config data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the best way to provide config to angular s services/factories. For example a pusher api key? I want to write a module that is reusable across multiple pusher accounts.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Simply create another service and pass it as a dependecy.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.factory('ProviderConfigService', function() {
  return {
    apiKey: '...'
  }
})
.factory('ProviderService', function(ProviderConfigService) {
  return {
    doSomethingWithApi: function() {
     var apiKey = ProviderConfigService.apiKey
   }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually just provide a constant for injection: [Angular Documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24provide#methods_constant)

Here's a code sample:

```
angular
    .module('myApp', [])
    .constant('apiKey', 'abc12345')
    .controller('myController', function($scope, apiKey) {
        $scope.key = apiKey;
    });
```

And [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZNEPD/) (although this injects to a controller for demonstration, it works equally well for services).

A big benefit of constants over more bulky services is that you can inject them into `config` blocks.